# Mercurial premerge = false only for specific files, = true for all others?

Tags: mercurial, merge

Is it possible for Mercurial to automatically merge all changes except for specifically nominated files? For the specific files there are some lines that may be overwritten so I want it to force a manual merge with the visual merge tool.

The use-case for this is pulling from a parent repo and building a different version of an app form the same code. The specific files would include the Visual Studio project file & AssemblyInfo file - I want to retain the version-specific references and .NET framework to build against. For more background of my scenario see http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/best-practice-to-maintain-different-build-configs-for-the-same-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can configure separate merge tools on a per-file basis, and they could differ only by pre-merge flag if you wanted:

```
[merge-tools]
mymergetool.priority = 100
mymergetool.premerge = True
mymergetool.args = $local $other $base -o $output
mymergetool.executable = /path/to/mergetool

manualmerge.priority = 100
manualmerge.premerge = False
manualmerge.args = $local $other $base -o $output
manualmerge.executable = /path/to/mergetool


[merge-patterns]
filename_to_never_automerge = manualmerge
```

Full details: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration