# Mercurial - how to force a merge for certain files?

Tags: mercurial, merge, hgrc

I am trying to force a manual merge for certain files per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919709/mercurial-premerge-false-only-for-specific-files-true-for-all-others) but it isn't working.  Certain pom files are being auto merged even though I believe I have configured my .hgrc correctly.  Any ideas?

I tried fiddling with the merge tools priority.  Originally we had `merge = bc` under `[ui]`  - removed this but it didn't help.

My .hgrc:

```
[ui]
editor = notepad
username = Boo Hoo <boo.hoo@who.com>
ssh = plink

[extensions]
fetch =
hgext.extdiff =
mq =
hgext.graphlog = 

[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3 =
cmd.examdiff = C:\Program Files (x86)\ExamDiff Pro\ExamDiff.exe
cmd.bc = C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe
opts.bc = /leftreadonly

[merge-tools]
bc.executable = C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp
bc.args = /leftreadonly /centerreadonly $local $other $base $output
bc.priority = 1
bc.premerge = True

manual.executable = C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp
manual.args = /leftreadonly /centerreadonly $local $other $base $output
manual.priority = 100
manual.premerge = False

[merge-patterns]
.hgtags = manual
pom.xml = manual
**\pom.xml = manual
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the [file name patterns](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1#patterns), and the fact that merge-pattern are glob by default, rooted at the root directory (see [hgrc `merge-pattern`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#merge-patterns)), you could try:

```
**/pom.xml
```

(to use the shell-style path separator '`/`' instead of '`\`')

or try a regex pattern:

```
re:.*[/\\]pom.xml$
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but didn't work sadly.  The premerge still happens.

Comment: @marcus: try removing `merge-tools` `bc`, and leave only one (the `manual`), to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Yes, it is still doing the premerge.  Weird.

Comment: I tried adding `merge = manual` under `[ui]` and then removing all the merge-patterns entries.  But that didn't work either.  Seems like premerge just doesn't work, or I'm doing something silly.  Latter likely..

Comment: @Marcus: at this stage, you may want to check if any of the `.hgrc` directives are taken into account. Is `.hgrc` actually read?

Comment: @Marcus: so the other test is to make a merge-tools actually work, first with `bc.premerge = True`, then with `False`.

Comment: @Marcus: for example, does `bc.executable` alone gets always executed when `bc.premerge = False`?

Comment: In our example, there are about 10 pom files that changed in the 'other' head.  When we do `hg merge`, the bc.executable is executed for 3 of the pom files.  The other 7 appear to 'fall victim' to the premerge and not bc.executable nor any other merge tools are executed for them.

Comment: @Marcus: so the 7 others are ones without any conflict, capable of being merged automatically, then? What is the version of Mercurial used during this merge? Is it the latest one? Would it be a more recent Mercurial release which would fix the `premerge` directive? (I just looked at http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew: nothing *directly* related to '`premerge`')

Comment: Correct, no conflicts on seven others.  Our version of Mercurial is 1.4.3.  I'm not sure if I can upgrade..

Comment: @Marcus: still, it would be worth testing if that "7-file-automatically-merged" behavior is consistent across different Mercurial releases. Since 1.4.3 is kind of old.